# A question on the proof of the De Bruijn-Erdos theorem

Tags: geometry

I just read a very short paper on the De Bruijn-Erdos theorem. It essentially states that if we have $n$ points and $m$ lines, where any two points lie on a line, and each line has at least two points, then there are at least as many lines as points.

The proof is in this [short paper](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1948-01.pdf). It is stated at the very top, and the proof I'm curious about begins in the middle of page 2 and ends at the top of page 3. I don't quite follow the inequalities 
$$
s_j\leq k_n\ \text{for}\ j>\nu
$$
that are found at the very top of page 3. Why would that fact that an index $j$ being greater than the minimum number of lines passing through a given point require that the number of points on that indexed line is at most the number of lines passing through that point? Apart from that I follow the rest. Does it violate one of the assumptions about the space? Thanks.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of a direct link to the paper, the computer I'm on requires that pdfs be downloaded directly, and not in the browser.

Answer (score 3):

All the inequalities in (3) are derived from (2). The first $\nu$ inequalities, up to the semicolon, follow because $a_i$ is not on $A_j$ for $i\neq j$, $i \leq \nu$, $j \leq \nu$. The remaining inequalities, $s_k \leq k_n$ for $j > \nu$, follow because $A_1$, $A_2$, ..., $A_\nu$ are the lines through $a_n$, and hence $a_n$ is not on $A_j$ for $j > \nu$.